# Logic App send Event to Event Hub - Status 404

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-eventhub

I try to get familiar with Azure logic apps therefor I try some simple things like receive request connect to database and / or event hub.

In case of send an event to an event hub I get the following error

> {"statusCode":"BadRequest","body":{"code":"ServiceProviderActionFailed","message":"The service provider action failed with error code 'BadRequest' and error message 'Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://eventhubXX.servicebus.windows.net/eventhubXX/myeventhub' could not be found. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions.  TrackingId:1234567-1234-1245-1254-1234562345_G15, SystemTracker:evneventhub01.servicebus.windows.net:eventhubxx/myeventhub, Timestamp:2021-09-15T08:41:35.'."}}

I copied the Connectionstring from the EventHub and pasted it into the Logic App.

and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Please help and/or give me a hint.
Thx!

Comment: I can say 'eventhubXX/myeventhub' is not a valid eventhub name. Eventhub name should not include '/'. You should check your Logic App configuration.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Serkant Karaca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4280620/serkant-karaca), 'eventhubXX/myeventhub' is not a valid eventhub name. Eventhub name should not include '/'.

To get the connection string from the Azure Event Hubs, refer this [MsftDocumentationSteps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-get-connection-string)

For more details on how to send/receive events from and to the event hubs - refer this [# Send events to and receive events from Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send)